# Why return is required in javascript function?

Tags: javascript

When i executed following `JavaScript` code, i got `undefined`

```
var ns=new String('hello world');
String.prototype.capitalAll=function(){
                                 this.toUpperCase()
                                       };
alert(ns.capitalAll()); // undefined
```

But, when i add `return`, it returns a value

```
var ns=new String('hello world');
String.prototype.capitalAll=function(){
                                 return this.toUpperCase() // added return
                                       };
alert(ns.capitalAll()); // HELLO WORLD
```

Why `return` is required here and in end of every function. I have seen use of `return` in many `javascript` frameworks.

Comment: Should be obvious, but unless you're returning a value from the function, the default `undefined` is returned!

Comment: I think you summed it in your own question: when you use `return`, it returns a value.

Comment: @adeneo please don't say that something should be obvious. the op is asking because he/she doesn't know.  we all had/have to start somewhere.

Comment: @henrybemis - based on the code above with prototyping etc. it's not the OP's first rodeo (hopefully), and what "return" does should be obvious, it is in fact so obvious that the OP has already answered his own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How else would you return data from a function call?

Functions like `Array.prototype.shift()` are transformative, in that they modify the array. Internally, they do something like `this[this.length] = newvalue` and actually modify `this` in some way.

But most functions are not transformative, they return the result.

Answer (score 1):

`return` allows you to define what a function passes back when its called.

Its not required to have a return value, you can have a function that returns nothing, it just modifies other variables or prints something and then continues.

`undefined` is returned when you don't specifically specify another value to be returned

Answer (score 0):

[What toUpperCase does:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)

The thing is that toUpperCase doesn't modify "this" in the first place. That is a function that returns a value.

Some methods modify the object they are called on (they modify "this").. and in those cases you could write the function like you had it. In this case though, you need to use the "return" value.